# How to make a button display a certain picture?

Tags: button

Hey everyone I know this question has been asked timelessly but I am a complete newbie to HTML, CSS and Javascript. I literally am on my fourth day of self learning how to code so please forgive me.

I want to test a page where if you click on a button it will display a picture, if you click on the other button it will display a different picture. Here is what I got so far, what would be by next steps and why? Thank you!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Just Two Buttons </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><center> Pick a button! </center></h1>
<img id="dog" src="https://i.ibb.co/x24nhsc/dog-image.jpg" style="display:none;>
<img id="cat" src="https://i.ibb.co/CsGsxJ5/cat-217679.jpg">
<button> Woof! </button>
<button> Meow! </button>
<script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will probably need javascript to do that. [Event listeners](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) is a good place to start - and [adding/removing CSS classes or styling](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp).

Comment: What would be the Javascript code to make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. The solution below uses `onclick` combined with `data-*` to reference which image a button should show or hide. Further, visibility requires the CSS class "visible" to be shown (try to avoid styling directly on the `style` attribute).

When an image should be shown, the existing visible image should be invisible. You could either store which one is shown, and only remove the class from that element - or as I have done, by removing it from all images.

To get the button we clicked, `this` is passed to the function in `onclick=myclick(this)`. That means that we can access the clicked buttons attributes, specifically the `data-href="dog"`. This is accessed as `element.dataset.href`.

```js
var dog = document.getElementById("dog");
var cat = document.getElementById("cat");

function myclick(element) {
    dog.classList.remove("visible");
    cat.classList.remove("visible");
    document.getElementById(element.dataset.href).classList.add("visible");
}
```

```css
.myimage {
    display: none;
}

.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Just Two Buttons </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><center> Pick a button! </center></h1>
        <img class="myimage" id="dog" src="https://i.ibb.co/x24nhsc/dog-image.jpg">
        <img class="myimage visible" id="cat" src="https://i.ibb.co/CsGsxJ5/cat-217679.jpg">
        <button onclick="myclick(this)" data-href="dog"> Woof! </button>
        <button onclick="myclick(this)" data-href="cat"> Meow! </button>
    </body>
</html>
```